# why my $(window).load(function() is not working in document.ready function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

my on windows.load function not working in document.ready

```
$(document).ready(function(){

       //this is for nimation
       $(".progress-bar-fill").css({"width":"100%","transition":"5s"});
      // my this function is not working
       $(window).load(function() {
        $(".overlay").fadeOut();

    });

});
```

Comment: It's not always guarenteed that the load event will happen after the document ready executes.  Move it outside of the ready.  There's no need for it to be in it.

Comment: See https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/3197

Answer (score 0):

Your code says:

- Load the document
- When the DOM is loaded, register a new hook to listen on when the window is loaded (images etc.) which will start the animation

However, by the time your window load registration happens, the window might already be loaded.

You also use the incorrect method to subscribe to the window loaded event.

Try:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
       //this is for nimation
       $(".progress-bar-fill").css({"width":"100%","transition":"5s"});
});

$(window).on("load", function() {
   $(".overlay").fadeOut();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="progress-bar-fill">progress bar</div>
<div class="overlay">overlay</div>
```

Comment: it is not working because it is jquery 3.0 and it does not support on load function

Comment: @MuhammadAsif eh, no. that's not true at all. the load event isn't a jquery event, therefore jquery can't not support it. it's just an ordinary event.

Comment: Updated answer with a working snippet with jQuery 3.0.0 (why are you not using the latest version though?). @MuhammadAsif please add more context to your question if this is not the behaviour you're after.